# load images and sounds with jquery ajax before displaying page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i started this little project, web app,  which uses a lot of little images and some mp3 sounds but i was not pleased with the fact that new images and sounds load over time as user discover new "places" so i came up with the solution to use `$.ajax` `GET` method to load all the graphic and sounds and then display page when all is ready. This is the code:

```
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < this.imagesNumber; i = i + 1) {
        (function(i) {
            $.ajax({
                url: self.images[i], // for example 'images/arrow.png'
                type: 'GET',
                complete: function(data) {
                    console.log("Completed.", i, self.images[i]);
                },
                progress: function(event) {
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        console.log("Loaded " + parseInt( (event.loaded / event.total * 100), 10) + "%");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Length not computable.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }(i));
    }
```

and then i do:

```
this.loadAssets();
$(window).load(function() {
    app.initialize();
});
```

It is really downloading all the stuff, but then when i try to use certain elements on the page some of them again keep downloading (only some are loaded from cache. To check that i monitor all that from within google chrom network tab.

So what is the difference beetween jquery internal asset call and my ajax call what im i missing?

Comment: Are you aiming to download _everything_ initially? Because that seems to be a _very_ bad approach.

Comment: this is something like mini game, user should not experience extra loading during play, every asset should be avialable to him before he uses it

Comment: Can post `js` at "when i try to use certain elements on the page" ? Is `$.ajax()` called again ? Is requirement to load all assets;  do stuff at elements after all assets loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem with a Card Game I was working on a few weeks ago. The problem lies in how some browsers handle the caching of images loaded via asynchronous means. I can replicate this issue in Firefox on my Laptop, but not my PC. I'm not sure what the actual problem is, but I know how to band-aid fix it.

Just move the loading of your images or assets into your main Javascript file. These files are loaded as the page is generated and stored in the respective local copy of the page in your cache. The files cached via Ajax, however, are not always saved in the same place as the current page depending on how much time elapses in the loading. I believe this is the key setting that is causing this unexpected behaviour, as it varies per system based on settings with different browsers, different caching aggressiveness, etc. Any files saved in the cache with the page will be loaded instantly (as expected), but any files saved *not* attributed with your page will need to be reloaded on request. If these subsequent reloads are saved in different locations again, you'll effectively have to reload these files again and again and again.

So, all the files you load with your Ajax call, load them all in your main Javascript without an Ajax call. For your mini game this is okay, because the user will be expecting a load period. Just make sure they know it's happening and there will be no harm done.